# what's wrong with my angular2 import code

Tags: angular, import

As code Below, Im new to angular2, why when i use "app/app.module" the light server returns an error:

```
import {AppModule} from "app/app.module";//wrong
import {AppModule} from "./app.module";  //right
```

> app/main.ts(5,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module '/app/app.module'.

what's the problem?is there any way to use `"app/app.module"`?

[this is the structure image, exactly flow the angular 2 tut.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUffk.jpg)

[I think the problem is because of tsconfig.json, from angular 2 tut. but I dont know how to fix it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c82R9.jpg)

thanks everybody

Comment: Is `app.module` in a subdirectory named `app` relative to where you are attempting the import?

Comment: please screen shot your directory structure including the files in it.

Answer (score 0):

### The both of your example are using a relative path

The path of the AppModule is relative to your current file.

> If you using Webpack or SystemJS to import, you should follow this
> constraint
>
> `AppModule _> same folder`
>
> `./AppModule -> inside a file`
>
> `../AppModule -> go out from current directory`

Comment: I think the problem is because tsconfig.json.   i just can use ./AppModule but not app/app.module